# SQL Server Criteria not working when values are NULL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to capture all values that are `FieldName <> 'Value'`, that will return records where FieldName is NULL, without saying `(FieldName <> 'Value' OR FieldName IS NULL`) for every criteria field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ISNULL(FieldName,'') <> 'Value'
```

Or use

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
<..your query..>
```

However, the ability to [set ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) is on its way out.